# How to prove equality of functions.

Tags: category-theory

Let $F:C\to D$ and $G:D\to C$ be functors such that $G\vdash F$.Let $x,y\in C$. Since,$G\vdash F$, we have that there is a natural bijection $j:D(Fx,Fy)\to C(x,GFy)$. Let $\eta:id_C\to GF$ be the unit of the adjunction. Note $\eta_{y_*}:C(x,y)\to C(x, GFy)$(this is post composition with $\eta_y$) is a function.  Now consider the function $F_{x,y}:C(x,y)\to D(Fx,Fy)$. How would I prove that $\eta_{y_*}=j\circ F_{x,y}$?

Comment: Try writing out the naturality square for $\eta$.

Comment: I have. But that doesn't help me at all.

Comment: I see that if $f\in C(x,y)$, then $\eta_y f)=GFf\eta_x$. I don't see how that helps me.

Comment: Naturality of $j$ is helpful too (looks like you'll need both). Don't forget the connection between $\eta$ and $j$.

Comment: Is it because $j=\eta_{x}^*G$ meaning $j(f)=\eta_{x}^*G(f)=G(f)\eta_x$?In our case, we would just replace $f$ with $Ff$.

Comment: Yeah, If you define $j$ in terms of $\eta$ you'll only need to apply the naturality of $\eta$ and the definition of $j$.